# Can I get correct $PATH when executing sudo -u db2inst -sh "db2"?

Tags: shell, sudo, path

I need to run `sudo -u db2inst1 sh -c "db2 connect to db; db2 set schema Edumate; db2 \"select * from edumate_settings\""` but I don't want to specify absolute path to db2

If I run `sudo -u db2inst1 sh -c "id;$PATH;ls /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2"`

I get correct $PATH where `/opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/` is present

```
uid=1002(db2inst1) gid=107(db2iadm1) groups=16(dialout),33(video),107(db2iadm1),108(db2fadm1),1001(eduserver)
sh: /sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib64/jvm/jre/bin:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin:/opt/firebird/bin:/opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/:/opt/eduserver/bin: No such file or directory
/opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2
```

But if I run `sudo -u db2inst1 sh -c "db2"` I get `sh: db2: command not found`

If I use the absolute path (I don't want to use absolute path in case it gets changed) I get db2 prompt.

Any suggestion how to call only `db2` in this command `sudo -u db2inst1 sh -c "db2 connect to db; db2 set schema Edumate; db2 \"select * from edumate_settings\""`

Answer (score 1):

In most configurations, sudo replaces the `PATH` environment variable by a compile-time default or a value specified in `/etc/sudoers`.

You can do the path lookup before passing the command to `sudo`.

```
db2=$(unset -f db2; unalias db2 2>/dev/null; command -v db2)
sudo -u db2inst1 sh -c '"$0" connect to db; "$0" set …' "$db2"
```

In the common case when you know that the command is not a function nor an alias in your current shell and that the full path doesn't contain any special character:

```
sudo -u db2inst1 sh -c "$(command -v db2) connect to db; $(command -v db2) set …"
```

Note the use of double quotes here, so that `$(command -v db2)` is evaluated in the outer shell. You can feed commands on standard input to save more typing:

```
sudo -u db2inst1 $(command -v db2) <<\EOF
connect to db
set …
EOF
```

Comment: Hm, I need to find the path as db2inst1 user not as current user. Current user doesn't have access to this file.

Comment: Could you explain why $PATH is displayed correctly for sudo -u db2inst1 but running a file that is in the $PATH fails?

Comment: @Radek Oh, I think I misread the question, your symptoms are not exactly the usual ones. What is the output of `sudo -u db2inst1 sh -c "type db2"`? Do you have access to the `sudoers` file, and if so, what are the relevant settings (the applicable `Defaults` lines and the line that let you run `db2` as `db2inst1`)?

Comment: `sudo -u db2inst1 sh -c "type db2"` gives me `sh: line 0: type: db2: not found`

Comment: What I am going to do is to run the sudo over ssh on lots of different servers as a root user. The setup on  the servers should be the same - hopefully - but I don't want to change anything.

Comment: @Radek Scratch that, I misread your question the *second* time. `sudo -u db2inst1 sh -c "id;$PATH;ls /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/bin/db2"` expands `PATH` in the outer shell. You do find `db2` in the current user's path, not in `db2inst1`'s path.

Comment: So what would be the answer if I want to run the code from php over ssh? That means on one line only?